# Recursion & Immutability in F#

Tags: recursion, f#

Consider the following simplistic example:

```
type Parent = { Children : Child list }
and Child = { Value : int ; Parent : Parent }

let rec children = [ { Value = 0 ; Parent = parent } ]
and parent = { Children = children }
```

The F# compiler is smart enough to correctly initialize these recursive objects, as can be verified by running

```
obj.ReferenceEquals(parent, parent.Children.Head.Parent)
```

Now, consider the following generalization:

```
let length = 100 // assume arbitrary

let rec children = List.init length (fun i -> { Value = i ; Parent = parent })
and parent = { Children = children }
```

This definition will result in a compiler error. My question is the following: is there any way I could make the above binding *without* resorting to reflection or mutable fields?

Comment: As a F# newbie, I would be interested in knowing what is the practical application of a code snippet like the one above.

Comment: The example itself is just a meaningless simplification that I knocked together. The more general problem is that of initializing cyclic instances of immutable data structures.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
let rec mkChild i = {Value = i; Parent = parent}
and parent = { Children = children }
and children = List.init length mkChild
```

Comment: So, what precisely are the limitations? I couldn't find anything in the spec.

Comment: That's slick - I tried binding children with list comprehension and that fails in this form and the original form too.

Answer (score 0):

I can't answer for `F#`, but I'm sure there is no way to do that in OCaml which is very close to F#. This is the same as defining a circular list:

```
let rec a = 1 :: 2 :: a;
```

In the case of recursive object definition, then you can't have function call along the recursive cycle because it means calling a function on a object which is not yet fully constructed.

More precisely in your example, you are trying to pass to `List.init` a closure `(fun i -> { Value = i ; Parent = parent })` but this closure can't be defined since `parent` is not yet fully defined.